# Passing Variable with EJS Templating

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using the Ejs templating engine for my expressjs project and despite passing my objects along to my view blog.ejs file, I am receiving an `blogpost not defined` error in my ejs file. Error is happening at my `<% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>` line. I figure that is has something to do with how im passing the object and its properties, but I followed guides and it appears correct.

routes.js:

```
//blog
    router.route('/blog') 

        // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
                });

        }) // END POST method


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res) {
            Blogpost.find(function(err, blogpost) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
                blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
                blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
                blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post

                res.render('pages/blog', {
                    title: blogpost.title,
                    author: blogpost.author,
                    content: blogpost.content,
                    date: blogpost.date
                });
            });
        }); // END GET method
```

blog.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="body-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <h1><%= blogpost.title %></h1>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>




    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not passing an array variable called `blogpost` to your template, you are instead passing these variables to your template:

```
title: blogpost.title,
author: blogpost.author,
content: blogpost.content,
date: blogpost.date
```

You could just do this `render()` instead of the one you currently have:

```
res.render('pages/blog', {
  blogpost: blogpost,
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and it solves my error message, but your solution renders an `undefined` result in the h1 tag when I load the page. Could this be because I have multiple entries in my database and it can't pull all of them at one time? Or is this more because the `[blogpost]` array isn't pulling in the data?

Comment: I've updated the solution. I guess what threw me off was that you had copied and pasted the `POST` code to your `GET` route handler (the `blogpost.title = ...` kind of lines).