# Send ejs field to a nodejs file

Tags: node.js, ejs, body-parser

I have the following ejs code.

```
 <form action="/"  class = "form-horizontal" method="post">
 <textarea class = 'form-control departureCode' name = "departureCode"     rows= "1"></textarea>
 </form>
```

This is my post handler code in routes.js file.

```
routes.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
            let departureCode = JSON.parse(req.body.departureCode);
            console.log(departureCode);
        });
```

I m not getting this to work successfully. I am getting undefined token error inside my post handler. Could you please help me?

Comment: you can not get data in ejs template if you post your data in route. You have to render your view and pass data in parameters then it will available in your ejs Template.
Use ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596615/passing-variable-with-ejs-templating

Comment: Sorry about the delayed reply. I tried using res.render it still gave me undefined token error for the req.body.departureCode value. May be I am missing something with the way by bodyparser module is set up.

Comment: I continued to read some more questions related to this issue and stumbled on one post where they have mentioned that may be there is no need to parse as it might have been already parsed. I tried removing JSON.parse and it worked :). But I must say your initial answer helped me understand that even if I wanted to send these values to the same ejs file, I have to use res.render. I am giving a tick to your answer for that. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed JSON.Parse from

```
let departureCode = JSON.parse(req.body.departureCode);
```

It worked. Also, made changes suggested by Yogesh Patel in the comments. Thank you all.