# is it possible to use process.env in ejs template?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ejs

im using **ejs** templating engine with **node.js** at backend and
 I want to secure my google map api key in **.env** file **but i can't access .env variable from ejs file** e.g:

```
<script
      async
      defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=process.env.MAP_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

i have tried some other ways too like:

```
<script
      src="https:/...?key=%process.env.MAP_KEY%&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

and also

```
<script
      src="https://...?key=[process.env.MAP_KEY]&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

i would be much obliged if some one bother to help me here. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596615/passing-variable-with-ejs-templating

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

In my examplel I am assuming you have the lib [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) installed

Here I'm loading the env before render the template, putting into a apikey variable and passing it to my template, in the template I'm interpolating the `apikey` with the script:

***routes/index.js***

```
require('dotenv').config()
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { apikey : process.env.APIKEY });
});

module.exports = router;
```

***views/index.ejs***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>tests</title>
  <style>
    #map-canvas {
      height: 700px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My map</h1>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
<script>
  showMap = function () {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: { lat: -7.1297, lng: -34.8219 },
      zoom: 10
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=apikey%>&callback=showMap">
</script>

</html>
```

***.env***

```
APIKEY=#!#!#@!lakdkjlkdjlas
```

Comment: but , this wlll be seen when we check the source code ryt?